# Replace multiple lines in a file with single line with variable containing escape characters

Tags: shell, sed

New to Shell Script. 
I have file. Sample like

**sample.txt**

```
some text1
txt2
element : /home/user/somelocation text1
loc : /home/user/somelocation text2
```

I'm trying to write shell script to replace lines containing `/home/user/`with `element : /home/testuser/somelocation text`

Both search text and replace test are variable to get from user.

```
#!/bin/csh

# Sample searchStr="/home/user/"
set searchStr=$1 

# Sample rplcStr="element : /home/testuser/somelocation text"
set rplcStr=$2
sed -i '/$searchStr/c\$rplcStr' sample.txt
```

But this isn't working.

Expected Output

```
some text1
txt2
element : /home/testuser/somelocation text
```

How to replace it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `sed`:

```
sed "/^element :/s|^.*$search.*$|$replace|g" file
```

**Test:**

```
$ search="/home/user/"
$ replace="element : /home/testuser/somelocation text"
$ sed "/^element :/s|^.*$search.*$|$replace|g" file
some text1
txt2
element : /home/testuser/somelocation text
loc : /home/user/somelocation text2
```

Comment: Thanks. I want have only one line after replacing and want to replace whole line. I just updated question with expected out too. ;) How to do that?

Comment: @sat It's not replacing those lines. Please check the updated question with expected output. I want to replace whole line with that line :)

Comment: @iUser, Yes. what about `loc :` ? It needs to replace or not. Your expected output missing `loc :`

Comment: @sat yeah it's missing. Because, whichever contains the search pattern I want to remove and add only one single line. (The matching lines will be adjacent always)